How do I fix "400. The server cannot process the request because it is malformed" logging into Google apps like Gmail?
I migrated to a new computer and updated OS. Now when I try to log-in to Google Drive or Gmail,  I get this error message:

400. That’s an error.
The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.

I am able to log in using other web browsers, but can't get it to work in my main browser (Firefox), even after turning off "tracking protection" and some privacy plugins.
Is there a way to get back into my account?

@Blindspots, your edits to my question and answer aren't correct.  I didn't mean Chrome when I said Google, I understand this to be browser-independent (the bad state arose in Firefox, but I don't have reason to believe it had to).  I didn't need to delete all of my cookies — which would have been much more disruptive — only the google domain cookies as I originally wrote.  Also the Google account includes more than Gmail, so I considered it helpful to include both words (Google and Gmail) to help people find this idea when stuck signing on to any Google services.

I tried to make it more clear based on my best guess as to what you meant.  If there is anything I got wrong I apologize and please correct it. You contrasted Google to other web browsers so my understanding was that you must mean Chrome. Google is a company, Gmail is an App and Chrome is a browser. If this is about logging into your Google account,  the app (Gmail) is less relevant. If this is about Firefox, it isn't mentioned anywhere.  If you want to help people in the future the best thing to do is be as clear as possible. No offense intended. Feel free to edit the question for clarity.

I fixed this by deleting my google domain cookies and going through the login again.
This may not work for everyone, but it is less radical than some of the suggestions I saw on the Google forums such as Account recovery or Booting in Safe mode.
